# Get total list of PC from CSV file using PowerShell

Tags: csv, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a CSV file containing a list of infected computers.  I would like to get a list containing the count of infected computers for each country.

UK PC

```
PC1002
PC1002
PC1003
PC1004
PC1004
PC1004
PC1004
```

France PC

```
FR2002
FR2004
```

Germany PC

```
DE3003
```

So the format of the table should be:

```
PC1  = 7
FR2 = 2
DE3 = 1
```

Update CSV file.

```
ComputerName    DetectionTime   UserName    Process ThreatName  Path    Severity    Category    CleaningAction  ExecutionStatus ActionSuccess   PendingActions  ErrorCode   RemainingActions    LastRemainingActionsCleanTime       
PC1002  10/06/2016 09:47    SYSTEM  Unknown PUA:Win32/DownloadSponsor   file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{5D31A17F-8C42-4E61-A22C-FE4298BD8EBA}-BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{EE7FA0FA-19AA-4E29-A6AE-7338C3BE10F8}-7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{5D31A17F-8C42-4E61-A22C-FE4298BD8EBA}-BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d|iexplore.exe;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{EE7FA0FA-19AA-4E29-A6AE-7338C3BE10F8}-7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85|iexplore.exe;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85 Severe  Potentially Unwanted Software   3   0   TRUE    0   0   0           
PC1002  10/06/2016 09:47    SYSTEM  Unknown PUA:Win32/DownloadSponsor   file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{5D31A17F-8C42-4E61-A22C-FE4298BD8EBA}-BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{EE7FA0FA-19AA-4E29-A6AE-7338C3BE10F8}-7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{5D31A17F-8C42-4E61-A22C-FE4298BD8EBA}-BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d|iexplore.exe;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{EE7FA0FA-19AA-4E29-A6AE-7338C3BE10F8}-7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85|iexplore.exe;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85 Severe  Potentially Unwanted Software   3   0   TRUE    0   0   0           
PC1003  10/06/2016 09:47    SYSTEM  Unknown PUA:Win32/DownloadSponsor   file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{5D31A17F-8C42-4E61-A22C-FE4298BD8EBA}-BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{EE7FA0FA-19AA-4E29-A6AE-7338C3BE10F8}-7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{5D31A17F-8C42-4E61-A22C-FE4298BD8EBA}-BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d|iexplore.exe;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{EE7FA0FA-19AA-4E29-A6AE-7338C3BE10F8}-7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85|iexplore.exe;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85 Severe  Potentially Unwanted Software   3   0   TRUE    0   0   0           
PC1004  10/06/2016 09:47    SYSTEM  Unknown PUA:Win32/DownloadSponsor   file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{5D31A17F-8C42-4E61-A22C-FE4298BD8EBA}-BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{EE7FA0FA-19AA-4E29-A6AE-7338C3BE10F8}-7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{5D31A17F-8C42-4E61-A22C-FE4298BD8EBA}-BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d|iexplore.exe;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{EE7FA0FA-19AA-4E29-A6AE-7338C3BE10F8}-7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85|iexplore.exe;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85 Severe  Potentially Unwanted Software   3   0   TRUE    0   0   0           
PC1004  10/06/2016 09:47    SYSTEM  Unknown PUA:Win32/DownloadSponsor   file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{5D31A17F-8C42-4E61-A22C-FE4298BD8EBA}-BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{EE7FA0FA-19AA-4E29-A6AE-7338C3BE10F8}-7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{5D31A17F-8C42-4E61-A22C-FE4298BD8EBA}-BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d|iexplore.exe;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{EE7FA0FA-19AA-4E29-A6AE-7338C3BE10F8}-7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85|iexplore.exe;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85 Severe  Potentially Unwanted Software   3   0   TRUE    0   0   0           
PC1004  10/06/2016 09:47    SYSTEM  Unknown PUA:Win32/DownloadSponsor   file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{5D31A17F-8C42-4E61-A22C-FE4298BD8EBA}-BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{EE7FA0FA-19AA-4E29-A6AE-7338C3BE10F8}-7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{5D31A17F-8C42-4E61-A22C-FE4298BD8EBA}-BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d|iexplore.exe;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{EE7FA0FA-19AA-4E29-A6AE-7338C3BE10F8}-7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85|iexplore.exe;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85 Severe  Potentially Unwanted Software   3   0   TRUE    0   0   0           
PC1004  10/06/2016 09:47    SYSTEM  Unknown PUA:Win32/DownloadSponsor   file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{5D31A17F-8C42-4E61-A22C-FE4298BD8EBA}-BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{EE7FA0FA-19AA-4E29-A6AE-7338C3BE10F8}-7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{5D31A17F-8C42-4E61-A22C-FE4298BD8EBA}-BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d|iexplore.exe;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{EE7FA0FA-19AA-4E29-A6AE-7338C3BE10F8}-7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85|iexplore.exe;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85 Severe  Potentially Unwanted Software   3   0   TRUE    0   0   0           
FR2002  11/06/2016 09:47    SYSTEM  Unknown PUA:Win32/DownloadSponsor   file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{5D31A17F-8C42-4E61-A22C-FE4298BD8EBA}-BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{EE7FA0FA-19AA-4E29-A6AE-7338C3BE10F8}-7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{5D31A17F-8C42-4E61-A22C-FE4298BD8EBA}-BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d|iexplore.exe;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{EE7FA0FA-19AA-4E29-A6AE-7338C3BE10F8}-7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85|iexplore.exe;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85 Severe  Potentially Unwanted Software   3   0   TRUE    0   0   0           
FR2004  12/06/2016 09:47    SYSTEM  Unknown PUA:Win32/DownloadSponsor   file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{5D31A17F-8C42-4E61-A22C-FE4298BD8EBA}-BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{EE7FA0FA-19AA-4E29-A6AE-7338C3BE10F8}-7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{5D31A17F-8C42-4E61-A22C-FE4298BD8EBA}-BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d|iexplore.exe;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{EE7FA0FA-19AA-4E29-A6AE-7338C3BE10F8}-7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85|iexplore.exe;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85 Severe  Potentially Unwanted Software   3   0   TRUE    0   0   0           
DE3003  13/06/2016 09:47    SYSTEM  Unknown PUA:Win32/DownloadSponsor   file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{5D31A17F-8C42-4E61-A22C-FE4298BD8EBA}-BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{EE7FA0FA-19AA-4E29-A6AE-7338C3BE10F8}-7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85;file:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{5D31A17F-8C42-4E61-A22C-FE4298BD8EBA}-BDA76FD6-F4D2-4274-2A10-28E5A595686F_1d1c3c632120f5d|iexplore.exe;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\LocalCopy\{EE7FA0FA-19AA-4E29-A6AE-7338C3BE10F8}-7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85|iexplore.exe;webfile:_c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\FilesStash\7ADD9B4F-194E-B272-C4FA-B5996C31067C_1d1c3c62e702f85 Severe  Potentially Unwanted Software   3   0   TRUE    0   0   0
```

Comment: can you post the structure of the csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its just a file containing one row (you didn't showed us the csv structure).  You can use the `Get-Content` cmdlet to load the file and use the `Group-Object` cmdlet to determine the count:

```
Get-Content  "your_path_here" | select -Skip 1 |
  Group { $_ -replace '([a-zA-Z]+)(.).*', '$1$2' } | 
  ForEach-Object { '{0} = {1}' -f $_.Name, $_.Count }
```

**Output:**

```
PC1 = 7
PC2 = 2
PC3 = 1
```

---

**Regex used:**

```
([a-zA-Z]+)(.).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: PC can be anything . It would be FR or GR

Comment: But always two characters?

Comment: PC name could be any country in would.

Comment: Yes all ways first two charactors will be same

Comment: This week I will have FRance germany and UK infected PC but next week it could be UK, USA and France

Comment: Okay... I also adopt the regex to reflect that. Please try to give us all details immediately when you ask a question.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. If i wont to put this into table how can i do that and also they is Speech mark at the begaining

Comment: Start a new question. This one ins answerd (please consider marking it as answerd as well).